# Line in set definition

Tags: math-operators

I'm trying a simple definition of a set.

My try: `$M=\{x\,|\,1\le x\le p-2\}$`

Is there a more comfortable way of getting a little space before and after the `|`? I'm thinking of something like the `\mod` which does the spacing on its own.

Comment: The correct command to use is `\mid`: `\{x\mid 1\le x\le p-2\}`. Many people add thin spaces (that is, `\,`) after `\{` and before `\}` when using `\mid`.

Comment: quite like `\mod` in fact: `\mid` :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The vertical bar is usually produced by using `\mid`, which prints the same symbol as `|` (or `\vert`, which is a synonym).

The difference is that `\mid` is treated as a relation symbol, so it will have thick spaces on its sides:

```
$M = \{ x \mid 1 \le x \le p-2 \}$
```

Many people (including Knuth) recommend adding thin spaces in order to detach the braces when using a condition with `\mid`:

```
$M = \{\, x \mid 1 \le x \le p-2 \,\}$
```

but

```
$X = \{1,2,3,4\}
```

when listing elements. Take your pick. For a small number of set denotations in the document this should not be a problem; but when there are many of them it's better to add a command, in order to ensure uniformity:

```
\newcommand{\Set}[2]{%
  \{\, #1 \mid #2 \, \}%
}
```

(the `%` aren't really necessary in this case) so you can call

```
$M = \Set{x}{1\le x\le p-2}$
```

and forget about the details. You'll also have the advantage that, if a fussy copy editor says they want colons and not vertical bars, it will be just a matter of changing `\mid` into `:` in the definition of `\Set`.

<sub>In a paper I was fine tuning for publication in a conference proceedings volume, sets were denoted in *three* different ways: sometimes the separation was with the bar, sometimes with a colon, sometimes with a semicolon. Being consistent in notation is a necessity, not an option.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

An interesting option for you may be to load the [braket](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/braket) package and use its commands `\set` and `\Set`. The lowercase-spelled version, `\set`, uses fixed-size (small) curly braces and central vertical bars; the uppercase-spelled version lets the "fence" symbols grow automatically with the material they enclose.

You could thus enter an expression such as

```
$M=\set{x|1\le x\le p-2}$
```

and let the package do the job of formatting the expression properly.