# How to write Math statement better in limits and spacing?

Tags: math-mode

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    c_{0} = 
    \left( (u_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{K} 
    | \lim\limits_{j \to +\infty} u_{j} = 0 \, \text{ converges } \right)
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

I do not like the

- unadjusted `limits` of lim,
- the manual spacing; I started to write `\,\,\,` things between things there but things get too manual fast.
- and the use of `\text{...}` because of printing to other formats

How can you write the statement better in limits and spacing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. `c_0 = \Bigl( (u_j)_{j\in\N} \subseteq \K \Bigm| \lim_{j\to\infty} u_j = 0 \Bigr)`?

Comment: What are unadjusted limits? Where do you use `\,\,\,`? What is wrong with `\text` or what are those other formats you are talking about? I would just type `\begin{equation*}
 c_{0} = \bigl((u_{j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{K} \bigm| \lim\limits_{j \to +\infty} u_{j} = 0 \text{ converges}\bigr)
\end{equation*}` and see no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Please explain the unadjusted comment. and what exaxtly is this, I do not recognize this syntax.

Comment: Can you make your question more precise, it is not clear to me what you object to. Maybe you are interested in [Line in set definition](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131674/35864), [How to automatically resize the vertical bar in a set comprehension?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448/35864) and [Define pretty sets in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13634/35864). This is purely mathematical nit-picking, but wouldn't one use set (curly) braces for this, and of course adding converges after one has already established the limit is 0 seems superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one of the following?

[image]

(The second equation, incidentally, reflects @moewe's observation that it seems redundant to require that a sequence have a (finite) limit *and* that it converge.)

If this isn't what you're looking for, please do clarify what you mean by terms such as "unadjusted limits" and "printing to other formats".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    c_{0} = 
    \Bigl( 
    (u_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{K} 
    \Bigm| 
    \text{$\lim_{j\to+\infty} u_{j} = 0$ converges}  
    \Bigr)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    c_{0} = 
    \bigl\{ 
    (u_{j}{)}_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{K} 
    \bigm| 
    \lim\nolimits_{j\to+\infty} u_{j} = 0  
    \bigr\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is very helpful `\Bigm|` making the thing clearer. Thank you!